# broadleaf admin allow non unique additions in adorned target collection

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have an adorned target collection. By design, admin does not allow adding same collection item twice. While this has been proven useful everywhere, in one particular scenario, I want to be able to add the same thing twice. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not a hook point that we expose.

Comment: I solved my problem by adding quantity field to adornedTargetCollection. So instead of adding multiple times, I simply increment quantity